# A visual roadmap of Ubuntu support

Tags: support, asking-questions

(Intent: Targeting the correct support audience 
when asking questions.)

**StackExchange, AskUbuntu, MetaAskUbuntu, chat, Canonical, Wiki, feature request, wish list, bug reports, etc.**


It's taken me at least 30 minutes to craft this 
question. 

I'm a visual guy, struggling to get a grip on the 
set up of Ubuntu's organization and its support 
network. If I try to *read* solutions to things, it's 
like listening to the **Charlie Brown**, *teacher 

talking sound*, 

"*Whu-whah, whu-whah-whu, whu-whu-whaaah*."

Is there a visual treatment of the Ubuntu world, 
to show how all of the Ubuntu universe fits together,
with perhaps colored boxes and lines, for example? 
Okay, throw in some arrows, too, if you'd like. 
Something that shows me 99-100% of Ubuntu's 
footprint all at once, instead of having to take 
weeks or months to put my own model together 
in my head.

I haven't used support enough times to have a clear 
map of things, yet I'm intimidated to ask questions 
sometimes out of fear of appearing daft for not
knowing enough to target a correct support group 
to ask the questions I need to ask, and not wanting 
to hack away at my reputation numbers, although I will 
say that the support which ***does*** come back through 
whatever channel in which I originally post is almost 
 
(if not always) supportive and understanding, even 
if posted in a wrong area and needs to be redirected to 
its "*proper*" area. ***That*** is a testament to the health 
of this community.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a start, It still needs work.

[image: Ubuntu support map]

Comment: Thank you. Like a vulcan mind-meld, it's sinking into my brain.

Comment: The bidirectional solve-yourself <=> reformat loop is pure genius.